# Can a Table-Type parameter be defined in the definition of a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Is it possible to define a table type as a parameter in the definition of a stored procedure?

Something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_People_insert]
      @People TABLE(Name VARCHAR(20), Age INT) READONLY
AS
    -- Do something here
GO
```

I know I can first create a Table Type like:

```
 CREATE TYPE [dbo].Person AS TABLE
 (
    [Name] VARCHAR(20), 
    Age INT
 )
```

and then define the procedure like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prco_People_insert]
      @People dbo.Person READONLY
AS
    -- Do something here
GO
```

But this will leave me with a bunch of user-defined Table Types hanging around in the Database.

I am looking to use Dapper to call the stored proc and pass in a list of Person types.

I can achieve the bulk insert functionality with an inline SQL statement and Dapper (see below) but am wondering whether the same can be acheived with stored procs and Dapper. Something like...

```
INSERT INTO dbo.People([Name], Age)
VALUES(@Name, @Age)
```

```
// C# Person class
public class Person(public string Name, public int Age)
```

```
// Pseudo Dapper call
connection.Execute(sql, new List<Person>(){ ... });
```

Comment: No, it cannot be.

Comment: As an alternative to a TVP, you could use json or XML to pass multiple rows to a proc or query.

Comment: Interesting idea @DanGuzman

Comment: I believe Dapper can pass directly to your SP look at  DynamicParameters `AddTable` method

Comment: @Stu, yes I am already using Dapper to pass user defined table types but I'm quickly realising that I need to create a new table type for almost every SP and this is resulting in a messy DB with loads of types hanging around

Comment: You only need a table type for each distinct type of object you're passing though, so if you're passing a list of objects that are always [string, int] just create one single generic tabletype.

Comment: I normally keep a bunch of standard one and two column table types, such as `dbo.StringList` and `dbo.StringInt` and `dbo.UniqueInt`

Answer (score 1):

As per @DanGuzman 's suggestion, passing in JSON works a treat

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prc_PeopleByJSON_insert]
    @PeopleJSON VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
    INSERT INTO PersonTable(Name, Age)
    SELECT Name, Age
    FROM OPENJSON(@PeopleJSON)
    WITH(Name VARCHAR(20), Age INT)
GO
```

Comment: Not the focus of the question, but you almost always want `NVARCHAR` for human-readable data so you have internationalization support. This is especially true for names, which may contain all sorts of characters from all sorts of languages.

Comment: Beware though that the data types, particularly varchar/nvarchar *must* match if you are going to use the values for filtering or joining, otherwise you'll force an implicit cast and SQL Server will be unable to utilise index seeks.

Comment: @Stu, In the example above the PersonTable had Name as VARCHAR(20). Would I be better off defining Name as NVARCHAR as well as having \@PeopleJSON NVARCHAR ?

Comment: That all depends on your requirements  - do you need to handle unicode data? If you don't, stick to *varchar* as *nvarchar* requires 100% more storage, both on disk and ram.